# I want to remove the top ImageView in RelativeLayout when a ImageView is added at bottom of stack but it is removing whole layout

Tags: javascript, android, android-recyclerview

//here is my recyclerview onScrollEvent

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        final int positionView = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        if (dy > 0) {
            if (positionView >= 3) {
                final View view = recyclerView.getChildAt(3);
                if (view != null && recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == positionView) {
                    TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 200, 0);
                    translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(positionView);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                            view.clearAnimation();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                        }
                    });
                    translateAnimation.setDuration(350);
                    view.setAnimation(translateAnimation);

                }
                createStackImageView();
                for (int i = stackView.getChildCount()-1; i >=1; i--) {
                    ResizeAnimation resizeAnimation = new ResizeAnimation(stackView.getChildAt(i));
                    resizeAnimation.setHeights(stackView.getChildAt(i).getHeight(), stackView.getChildAt(i - 1).getHeight());
                    resizeAnimation.setWidths(stackView.getChildAt(i).getWidth(), stackView.getChildAt(i - 1).getWidth());
                    resizeAnimation.setDuration(250);
                    stackView.getChildAt(i).startAnimation(resizeAnimation);
                    if(i==1){
                            stackView.removeView(stackView.getChildAt(i));
                            stackView.invalidate();
                            stackView.requestLayout();
                        }
                }
                stackView.invalidate();
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

//And this is the method where i create a imageview in relativelayout

```
private void createStackImageView() {
    fourthStack = new ImageView(getActivity());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
        (1, 1);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    fourthStack.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    fourthStack.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    fourthStack.setBackgroundColor(color);
    fourthStack.requestLayout();
    stackView.addView(fourthStack, layoutParams);
}
```

Now my main problem is when the RecyclerView is scrolled i create image at bottom so that there is number of stack dynamically.When this ImageView is created at bottom the top most image in RelativeLayout should be removed so that there will be no memory issue.But what happens for me is it is removing the whole stack i have created. I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

When u remove the ImageView from top It might have a relative connection to the bottom elements. So when you remove the image from top the views with relative connection to the removed view would go invisible. If you are using GONE method to remove the top view Try using Invisible and check whether the same is happening

Comment: with visibility gone and invisible both this problem will not appeared but will it free the memory

Comment: are you having the same issue.?

Comment: no i am not getting the same issue but when scrolling this dissappeared image will not free up the memory which is causing my recycler view shaking